# How to detect shake on the iPhone using Cocos2D?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, accelerometer, shake

I know how to do shake for the iPhone has been asked a million times on here, but I can't seem to find anything useful regarding the accelerometer with Cocos2D. Everything i have found involves using views and I don't think i am using any views in Cocos2D, if I am they are hidden from me I think. I want to be able to tell when any sort of shake has occured within a CCLayer class?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out. In the layer class you need to put these lines;

```
self.isAccelerometerEnabled = YES;
[[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setUpdateInterval:1/60];
shake_once = false;
```

Then implement this function in the layer class;

```
-(void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {

float THRESHOLD = 2;

if (acceleration.x > THRESHOLD || acceleration.x < -THRESHOLD || 
    acceleration.y > THRESHOLD || acceleration.y < -THRESHOLD ||
    acceleration.z > THRESHOLD || acceleration.z < -THRESHOLD) {

    if (!shake_once) {
        int derp = 22/7;
        shake_once = true;
    }

}
else {
    shake_once = false;
}

}
```

shake_once is just a boolean to stop one shake from being registered more than once.

Comment: Note that `1/60` evaluates to 0 because you are working with integers. (Try `1.0f / 60.0f` for 0.016~ result)
Also `isAccelerometerEnabled` is deprecated. Use `self.accelerometerEnabled`.